# Set changed size during iteration

Tags: python

I'm new to python coming from a c++ background. I was just playing around with sets trying to calculate prime numbers and got a "Set changed size during iteration" error.

How internally does python know the set changed size during iteration?

Is it possible to do something similar in user defined objects?

Answer (score 6):

The pythonic way to filter sets, lists or dicts is with list [or dict] expressions

```
your_filtered_set = set([elem for elem in original_set if condition(elem)])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to do so with a user-defined object: just set a flag each time you modify the object, and have the iterator check that flag each time it tries to retrieve an item.

Generally, you should not modify a set while iterating over it, as you risk missing an item or getting the same item twice.

Comment: I think java uses a modification count that is updated each time an element is set, added or deleted. The iterator copies the count when it is created and checks against this number each time it retrieves an element.

Comment: how do I risk to get the same twice if it is a set?